# How to exclude more than one group in a groupby using python?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have grouped the number of customers by region and year joined using groupby in Python. However I want to remove several regions from the region group.

I know in order to exclude one group from a `groupby` you can use the following code:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Region'])
df1 = df.drop(grouped.get_group(('Southwest')).index).
```

Therefore I initially tried the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Region'])
df1 = df.drop(grouped.get_group(('Southwest','Northwest')).index)
```

However that gave me the apparent error `('Southwest','Northwest')`.

Now I am wondering if there is a way to drop several groups at once instead of me having to type out the above code repeatedly for each region I want to remove.

I expect the output of the final query to be similar to the image shown below however information regarding the Northwest and Southwest regions should be removed.
[image: Groupby results]

Comment: You should provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `df1 = df.drop(grouped.get_group(('Southwest','Northwest')).index)`. `grouped.get_group` takes a single name as argument. If you want to drop more than one group, you can use `df1 = df.drop((grouped.get_group('Southwest').index, grouped.get_group('Northwest').index))` since `drop` can take a list as input.

As a side note, `('Southwest')` evaluates to `'Southwest'` (i.e. it's not a tuple). If you want to make a tuple of size 1, it's `('Southwest', )`